# OBIEE Recipients can't see all other recipients of a sent email

Tags: obiee

I am trying to figure out how to show all recipients in email sent by OBIEE ..

I am totally lost in EM, since I am not able to find where is this configuration

I tried to google for it but found nothing ..

Do you know where this could be set or if it is even possible?

example:

I will sent an analysis created in OBIEE to me@example.com and you@example.com .. but I (me@example.com) can't see you@example.com recieved it too, because it is (most probably) sent as bcc ...

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log into EM using Admin credentials
2. Navigate to Mail tab (Business Intelligence > coreapplication > Deployment>Mail
3. Click Lock and Edit Configuration to enable changes to be made.

[image]

4. You should see an Addressing Method radial button. Select To instead of Bcc.
5. Click Apply, and then click Activate Changes.
6. Return to the Business Intelligence Overview page and click Restart.